# Android data binding: cannot inject an attribute into "include" tag

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding

I'm trying to create a reusable layout `included.xml` which then could be injected into other layouts and customized via tag attributes. Here's what I have:

`res/layout/parent.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/com.myself.fancyapp"
    >

    <include layout="@layout/included"
            app:src123="@drawable/my_icon" />

</layout>
```

`res/layout/included.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    >
    <data>
        <variable name="src123" type="android.graphics.drawable.Drawable" />
    </data>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:src="@{src123}" />
</layout>
```

`app/build.gradle`:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    ....
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

As an outcome, the button which I try to inject doesn't contain any image at all.

If in `parent.xml` I change `xmlns:app` to `res-auto`, I have the following error in `app/build/intermediate/data-binding-layout-out/debug/layout/parent.xml`:

> Error:(17) No resource identifier found for attribute 'src123' in package 'com.myself.fancyapp'

Does anybody have an idea why this happens and how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` keep this in parent.xml and see the output

Comment: @RaviRupareliya Thanks for the suggestion but, as mentioned in the last part of my post, it throws a compile time error.

Comment: for a confirmation are you implementing DataBinding in a class where you are using parent.xml? or you are simply using `setContentView` or `inflater` for parent.xml?

Comment: @RaviRupareliya I just use `setContentView(R.layout.parent)`, I don't implement DataBinding in class.

Comment: Than you must have to use DataBinding in that class also

Comment: @RaviRupareliya thanks for the suggestion. I tried to use `DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.parent);` in `onCreate` but it didn't change anything...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're not using binding syntax for the variable:

```
<include layout="@layout/included"
        app:src123="@drawable/my_icon" />
```

should be:

```
<include layout="@layout/included"
        app:src123="@{@drawable/my_icon}" />
```

Unrelated, but I don't think that includes are allowed as the root element of a layout. I believe that you're going to have to have a normal View surrounding the include.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/com.myself.fancyapp"
    >

    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <include layout="@layout/included"
                app:src123="@{@drawable/my_icon}" />
    </FrameLayout>
</layout>
```